# Can a vscode extension create an explorer context menu for a specific file?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm writing a extension for vscode. I just want my context menu just show on when I right click on my file (ex: `my_special_name_1.py`). So I added this contribution point to `package.json`:

```json
"contributes": {
    ...,
    "commands": [
        {
            "command": "command.hello",
            "title": "Hello my file"
        },
        ...
    ],
    "menus": {
                "explorer/context": [
                    {
                        "when": "resourceLangId == python",
                        "command": "command.hello"
                    }
                ]
            },
    ...
}
```

But this will show my command "Hello my file" on all `.py` files. How to let it just be shown only on my files (ex: `my_special_name_1.py`, `my_special_name_2.py`, ...)? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can match the file name against a regex by using the `=~` operator:

```json
{
    "when": "resourceLangId == python && resourceFilename =~ /my_special_name_[0-9]+\\.py/",
    "command": "command.hello"
}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @Gama11 , i was looking for this. if we bind with "resourceLangId == python" is it possible to identify which file has been clicked on in explorer?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51961457/how-to-get-file-name-or-path-in-vscode-extension-when-user-right-click-on-file-i/51971599#51971599.