# VS Code 'when' clause contexts - Anyway to get filepath when right clicking in the explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to show certain commands when right clicking on an item in the explorer based on these conditions:

1. If right clicked item is a folder (this is working).
2. If right clicked item's filepath contains a certain folder name (not sure how to do).

Can anyone shed some light or point me in the right direction? I've looked through this [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_when-clause-contexts) for 'when' clauses but can't seem to find anything.

Using 'resourceFilename' only returns the name of the file and not the filepath so I'm unable to determine if it is nested under a certain folder name.

```
"menus": {
  "explorer/context": [
    {
      "when": "explorerResourceIsFolder && if targetfilepath.includes('x')",
      "command": "extension.mycommand",
      "group": "myGroup@1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a vscode extension create an explorer context menu for a specific file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52382136/can-a-vscode-extension-create-an-explorer-context-menu-for-a-specific-file)

Comment: 'resourceFilename' only returns the name of the file right? I'm trying to determine if target file is nested under a certain folder name.

Comment: Hm, it appears you're correct. Just checked with the "Developer: Inspect Context Keys" command. I also don't see any other context keys that might help with this here.

Answer (score 1):

RegExp?

```
"when": "resourceFilename =~ /docker/"
```

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_keyvalue-when-clause-operator