# How to get the selected folder in explorer in vscode? (left mouse clic event does exist?)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

for my first extension, i'd like to create source file and header file in the selected folder from explorer. A similar question has been post here, but i couldn't work the proposed solution in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51961457/how-to-get-file-name-or-path-in-vscode-extension-when-user-right-click-on-file-i).

In my package.json:

```
    "activationEvents": [
    "onCommand:tima.getSelectedFolder"
],
"main": "./out/extension.js",
"contributes": {
    "commands": [
        {
            "command": "tima.getSelectedFolder",
            "category": "Tima",
            "title": "Create a folder containing the source and header files"
        }
    ],
    "menus": {
        "explorer/context": [{
            "command": "tima.getSelectedFolder",
            "when": "explorerResourceIsFolder",
            "group": "Tima"
        }]
    }       
},
```

Next, in my extension.ts:

```
    import * as vscode from 'vscode';
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    let disposable_getSelectedFolder = vscode.commands.registerCommand('tima.getSelectedFolder', (uri:vscode.Uri) => {
            let selectedPath = uri.fsPath;
            if(selectedPath){
                vscode.window.showInformationMessage(selectedPath);
            }else{
                vscode.window.showInformationMessage("selectedPath n'a pas été défini");
            }           
        });
    context.subscriptions.push(disposable_getSelectedFolder);
}
```

The show information message tell me:
Command 'Tima: Get the selected folder' resulted in an error (Running the contributed command: 'tima.getSelectedFolder' failed.)
[edit]
(i answer myself... snif): the error message is due to the fact that I called the command by the command palette... But this sample need to be call by the contextuel menu...

Is it possible to retrieve the same information on a left click event? Does it exist?

Comment: Where is `getCurrentFolder` in your source code? Why is `getSelectedFolder` not in your  package.json? What is category `Tima`?

Comment: getCurrentFolder was replaced by getSelectedFolder. it's an error from me when i paste the text. getSelectedFolder is in "explorer/context" section and i add it in "commands" section. Tima is a name to identificate my commands in th command palet.

Comment: Why don't you edit your question to reflect the correct files and error message?

Comment: I just did it, thanks ;)