# How to give an argument to command "explorer.newFile" in Visial Studio Code extension development

Tags: javascript, api, visual-studio-code, command, vscode-extensions

How to give an argument to command `explorer.newFile` in Visual Studio Code extension development?
I just want to add create a file with certain name in explorer view and then open it and insert a snippet, these operations will be realized in a function .Help ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could certainly be wrong but I am not sure `explorer.newFile` will take an argument.

Nevertheless, this function will do what you want: create a file, open it, and insert an existing snippet:

```js
async function createFileOpen() {

  const we = new vscode.WorkspaceEdit();

  const thisWorkspace = await vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders[0].uri.toString();

  // if you want it to be in some folder under the workspaceFolder: append a folder name
  // const uriBase = `${thisWorkspace}/folderName`; 
  // let newUri1 = vscode.Uri.parse(`${uriBase}/index.js`);

  // create a Uri for a file to be created
  const newUri = await vscode.Uri.parse(`${ thisWorkspace }\\myTestIndex.js`);
  
  // create an edit that will create a file
  await we.createFile(newUri, { ignoreIfExists: false, overwrite: true });

  await vscode.workspace.applyEdit(we); // actually apply the edit: in this case file creation

  await vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(newUri).then(
    async document => {      
      await vscode.window.showTextDocument(document);
      // if you are using a predefined snippet
      await vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.action.insertSnippet', { 'name': 'My Custom Snippet Label Here'});
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!By the way,Do you know how to get the folder location selected by the right  click?

Comment: Yes, I believe I have that working but you should ask a separate question on it.

Comment: And see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51961457/how-to-get-file-name-or-path-in-vscode-extension-when-user-right-click-on-file-i/51971599#51971599